# After upgrading XAMPP 5.6 to XAMPP 7.2, I have --> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, xcode

I have a problem with my result on PHP code after upgrading the XAMPP 5.6 to XAMPP 7.2. in my MacPro.
What is an adjustment to fix the code in PHP script? because they gave me a warning:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in ...

My code:

```
<?php

include ("../inc/link.php");

    $alert  =   "none";

    if(isset($_POST["btn-login"]))  {
    //echo "Run Action Of Form Login";

    //echo $_POST["username"];
    //echo $_POST["password"];

    $username   = $_POST["username"];
    $password   = $_POST["password"];
    $query          =   mysqli_query($conex,"SELECT * FROM table_admin  WHERE adm_name='".$username."' AND adm_password='".md5($password)."' "); 
    $count          = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    echo        $count;

}

?>
```

Comment: Check `mysqli_error($conex)` for any clues

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$conex = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","javamartDB") or die ("Can not connect to the database");

    $alert  =   "none";

    if(isset($_POST["btn-login"]))  {
    //echo "Run Action Of Form Login";

    //echo $_POST["username"];
    //echo $_POST["password"];

    $username   = $_POST["username"];
    $password   = $_POST["password"];
    $query      = mysqli_query($conex,"SELECT * FROM table_admin "); 
    $count      = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($count)>0){
 while($row=  mysqli_fetch_row( $query));
        print_r($row[0],$row[1]);
        die;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: please checked this answer and let me know if any issue

Comment: thanks a lot Sanjay...highly appreciated. But, they exceed more warning, like this:  

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/javamart/admin/login.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/javamart/admin/login.php on line 13

Comment: I have a doubted to variable $row and $res?

Comment: This is the link.php       <?php
 
 $conex = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","javamartDB") or die ("Can not connect to the database");

?>

Comment: Theodore@@ use updated answere and let me know if any issue

Comment: still won't work bro. sorry for late answer, coz I did some experiment from your answer, but still failed, The mistake were in this code if(mysqli_num_rows($count)>0){
 while($row=  mysqli_fetch_row( $query));  to warn mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in. & mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in ...Any suggestion? thank u bro.

Comment: Theodore@@wait for reply

Comment: I am sorry...the version is XAMPP 7.1.6. is it any difference with XAMPP 7.2. I've been told?